# No NetworkManager applet and service

Tags: networking, network-manager

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10 Mini with MATE Desktop, and I've also installed network-manager and network-manager-gnome. The problem is that the nm-applet is missing from the tray.

Even though this may look like a trivial question, I've tried most of the solutions I've found but to no avail. The interesting things I've found out are:

- Even though network-manager and network-manager-gnome are installed, there is no such service known as NetworkManager or network-manager. However, after I login and go to a terminal and type **sudo NetworkManager**, the response I get is: **NetworkManager is already running (pid 2447)** (even though it is not registered as a service / daemon, at starts automatically.
- Even though nm-applet is set to start automatically(I have it registered in Startup Applications), it doesn't appear in the notification area, and this indicates that it cannot connect to the network manager service. However, when I start it manually via the terminal, it appears and works flawlessly(and it shows that the networks are managed by network-manager, not by another service).

  Below are some information relevant to my problem:
  The contents of /etc/network/interfaces:

> # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
> # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
>
> # The loopback network interface
>
> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback

The contents of /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

> [main]
>
> plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
>
> dns=dnsmasq
>
> [ifupdown]
>
> managed=true

The contents of /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state

> [main]
>
> NetworkingEnabled=true
>
> WirelessEnabled=true
>
> WWANEnabled=true
>
> WimaxEnabled=true

Is there any way I could solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the problem with the help of **[this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2186487)** on ubuntuforums.

The autostart file located here: **/etx/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop**

contained this certain line:

**AutostartCondition=GNOME3 unless-session gnome**

I removed it, and now nm-applet shows correctly.